What's wrong with this time difference calculation query?
I'm trying to add a column called ride_length to my table to calculate the time difference between the started_at and ended_at columns with the query below but I'm not getting anywhere. What am I doing wrong?
ALTER TABLE clean_ttd
ADD COLUMN ride_length AS
  (TIME(strftime('%s',ended_at) - strftime('%s',started_at),` 'unixepoch'))




started_at
ended_at




0023-07-10 04:57:00 UTC
0023-07-10 05:00:00 UTC


0023-10-15 01:36:00 UTC
0023-10-15 01:50:00 UTC


0023-10-21 01:17:00 UTC
0023-10-21 01:27:00 UTC


0023-08-08 19:00:00 UTC
0023-08-08 19:02:00 UTC



As stated above, I tried this query and got no where with the query.
ALTER TABLE clean_ttd
ADD COLUMN ride_length AS
  (TIME(strftime('%s',ended_at) - strftime('%s',started_at), 'unixepoch'))

I was hoping for a new column to show me the difference in time after subtracting the ended_at time from the started_at time.

Can you please tag with proper database? E.g. MySql, MSSql, etc.

You might find unexpected things happening if you don't really mean the year 23. I guess you mean the year 2023, in which case you should use that ;)

what does "got nowhere" mean ? no output  ? error message ? difference between expected output versus actual output ? (in that last case, please give them!)

Why add a field to table to save calculated result when this should just be done in query when needed?

@Justinas just tagged the proper database

@AndrewMorton so what happened was when I imported the csv file, it changed the year from 2023 to 0023. Is there a way to alter the table to have all 0023 values changed to 2023?

@Pac0 ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN does not support generated columns yet at [2:13] is the error I'm getting. So no output.

@June7 I can. I just rather add a column. What would the query to calculate what I'm trying to calculate be though?

Add field then run UPDATE action. Fixing the date structure is another issue. Maybe run a Replace() on the 0023 part and UPDATE.
